# How much time did Joseph Sisko spend on DS9?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Correct me if I'm wrong (or have missed something) but events described in [Far Beyond the Stars episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Far_Beyond_the_Stars_(episode)), seen *from DS9 perspective* seems to be lasting a single day.

It also seems, that in the beginning of the episode, Joseph Sisko welcomes his son and grandson and in the end of episode he seems to be quickly saying goodbye.

How can that be or what am I missing? From [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/33052/7885) we can learn that the *Defiant* needs at least 10-11 days to travel between DS9 and Earth, so any regular transportation ship will take this for let's say at least half a month.

Should we assume that Joseph Sisko spent an entire month traveling to see his son and grandson for a total of a single day? Where am I lost here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### His total time on the station seems to be about a week.

The [original screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/538.txt) indicates that Joseph Sisko has been there for several days before his son passes out

> **SISKO:** (nods) *Look, Dad... I know I haven't been very good company **the last few days.***

and stays for a three more days after the incident

> **A couple of days later.** Sisko is standing by the window, drinking a
>   cup of raktajino. The door CHIMES.
>
> **SISKO:** Come in.
>
> The door OPENS and Joseph Sisko ENTERS.
>
> **JOSEPH:** *How're you feeling, son?*
>
> **SISKO:** *Okay.*
>
> **JOSEPH:** *I'm done packing. Transport leaves at eight in the morning.*

Comment: @trejder - I'd be willing to hazard that a few days might be as many as 4 or 5. Given the relative distance of the station (and hence the fact that direct transport may not be available), Joseph's trip duration might be limited by the transport connections he can make. If he stays longer, it might take him longer to get back